# Indirect misdeanor prosecution

Tags: united-states, crime

Let us say person "A" has wilfully committed a misdemeanor, such as vandalism, and he testifies truthfully that person "B" caused him to commit the crime by suggesting it and offering an immaterial reward. Is B guilty of vandalism? Is A still guilty of vandalism? What if A committed a felony instead, such as murder?

**EDIT**
This is a question about laws in the United States of America

Comment: Laws vary around the world. If you would like a specific answer to your question then please consider adding the relevant jurisdiction tag.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: In the US this may vary from one state to another.

Comment: Depending on the specifics, it may be the case that both A and B are guilty of conspiring to commit the underlying offense. However, this would greatly depend on exactly what B said and did in furtherance of the alleged conspiracy. If B just vaguely suggested that "somebody" ought to commit a crime, that is likely to be protected speech under *Brandenburg v. Ohio.* But if B was more explicit and direct, or actively participated in some indirect way, then a charge of criminal conspiracy starts to look a lot more reasonable.

Comment: A charge of accessory might also be possible, again depending on the detailed fact6s.

Comment: @Kevin: That sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. B has either solicited A's offense (depending on what you mean by an "immaterial reward") or aided and abetted it through encouragement.

In most jurisdictions, A and B would be subject to the same liability and punishment.